# Is there any way to retrieve a user submissions statistics through a Rest call on spoj?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, rest, http

I am trying to develop a site which allows user to create developer profiles. I would like to link it with spoj, so that, I can show his submissions, passed/failed in the profile page .

I would like to know Does spoj  has any REST api support to fetch the user statistics. or any URL patterns like `/stats/username` which will return a Html page upon which I can scrap for useful data .

Note : I have checked the tools from spoj make and none of them are working with the new version. I am able to get my user data by visiting `/status/username/signedlist`. But that only works for logged in users and it is not public.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no way to know spoj user stats through rest call .
Although you can scrap /users/username/problem_code page to know valid submissions.

Example of the project is located here . 
https://github.com/aravindballa/MRNDLeaderboard